# The amount of memory used by each process

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I have a mysql server running debian with 2GO of RAM.
I would like to know the amount of memory used by each process.

I thought ps -aux was the command and options for it. But I only see 90 MO used by several processes and free -m tells me that 1400 MO are used.

Is there a way to have a better view with the processes and the memory used by them ?

```
srv-datax:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2015       1476        539          0          0         70
-/+ buffers/cache:       1405        609
Swap:          486          0        486
```

Answer (score 2):

You should post your free output so we know you are reading is correctly. Memory usage on Linux for a process is hard to nail down specifically, if you *really* want to get into the details and have a recent kernel, check `cat /proc/<pid>/smaps`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#top
```

is a good option

```
#top -H
```

lets you monitor all Threads

```
#top -U root
```

this kind of using '-U' switch lets you monitor user-specific listing

Answer (score 0):

Top does a good job, look for these headers:

```
VIRT  RES  SHR S %MEM
```

Comment: srv-datax:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2015       1476        539          0          0         70
-/+ buffers/cache:       1405        609
Swap:          486          0        486

Answer (score 0):

Another option along the same lines as what AbhishekKr suggested: `ps aux` will give you a breakdown of the memory used by every process on the system.

**VSZ** => Virtual Size (physical RAM+swap used), **RSS** => Resident Size (physical RAM only).
The **%MEM** column reflects the % of physical RAM used if memory serves, I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: The problem is those are kind of messed up, they don't properly account for shared memory, so if you have a bunch of instances of a program, it will show that memory over and over again.  The end result being that summed RSS overestimates memory.

Comment: For example: `ps -A -o rss,cmd | grep oracle | awk '{print $1}' | (tr '\n' '+'; echo 0) | bc` returns `12733324`, where as free -buffers/cache is `1741736`

Comment: That's true: `ps` includes shared memory in RSZ.  If you're summing up the data this can lead to over-counting, but it's still a good indicator of rough size for a single process if you don't mind that fuzz.  If you want to exclude shared pages `top`'s output is probably better as it lists shared memory separately.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Kyle Brandt suggested, you could use the Tool `pmap` which nicely summarizes the information found in /proc/<pid>/smap. If you use the `-d` option, it will show you how much memory is mapped, shared and set private. This, IMHO, provides a good view.

I can also suggest reading [this interesting article](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html) about memory usage.